# Generate Print Quality PDF using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image, printing, pdf-generation, asp.net-2.0

I've recently created a feature on a website which will generate a PDF document containing images and text. These will then be printed out and stuck onto coffee mugs.

I've done this using Winnovative HTML to PDF conversion.

Everything works fine, however the image quality is far too low for print, and looks rubbish on the mugs.

I've been told the reason for this is because the image will only be 70dpi (screen quality), when it needs to be 300dpi (print quality).

Is there a way I can generate these PDFs so that the images are print quality?

Comment: Is there a reason why they have to be PDF? Can you not just create an image file for download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have really good luck with iTextSharp, I build many good quality pdfs with it. But I build the pdfs from scratch, and print directly. Would it be possible for you to recreate the page content in the code and print? It's pretty simple to do, and there is a lot of resources/examples out there to build from.

If not, there's several products out there like [pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/). I can't say I've used it myself. But I've heard of people using it for high quality html to pdf, but you have to pay for the privilege.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when you say build from scratch, what code are you using to build it? Is it a HTML string? I'm wondering whether a HTML string would then get rendered, and therefore reduce quality anyway?

Comment: There's a lot of examples out there to look at, like [this](http://goo.gl/PdjfM). The iTextSharp document would be strictly in the code-behind. On an event you could go read the content of a page and place it in a new pdf your generating behind the scenes. You could build it a couple different ways depending on what you're trying to reconstruct. Just find an example that's similar and work from there.

Comment: Ah I see, Cheers I'll give it a go now!

Comment: I've tried iTextSharp but it still seems to lower the quality :/

Comment: There's a lot of factors to take into consideration when high quality is your goal, I'd have to see the code and your files to say how to get the best quality. Posts like [this one](http://goo.gl/uUw6n) have some answers that might help. Quality can be effected by how you add images. You can create a really large image, and then scale it down to fit the page. [This](http://goo.gl/5jaDZ) article can tell you more on working with images. If all else fails, contact support at pdfcrowd (or another paid product) to see if they can meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a raster image in PDF its quality becomes lower and lower and you zoom in PDF document. For a good comparison you should have 100% zoom level in PDF viewer. If you have a higher resolution picture you want to use in PDF instead of the picture from HTML the you can do this as you can see in the [Replace Images from HTML with Higher Quality Images in PDF Demo](http://www.winnovative-software.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/Images_Quality/Replace_with_Higher_Quality_Images.aspx) . The relevant C# code from that demo is:

```
protected void convertToPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
    HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

    // Set license key received after purchase to use the converter in licensed mode
    // Leave it not set to use the converter in demo mode
    htmlToPdfConverter.LicenseKey = "fvDh8eDx4fHg4P/h8eLg/+Dj/+jo6Og=";

    // Select all images from HTML page
    htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlElementsMappingOptions.HtmlElementSelectors = new string[] { "img" };

    // Exclude the original images from rendering becuase they will be replaced by an image from local file system
    htmlToPdfConverter.HiddenHtmlElementsSelectors = new string[] { "img" };

    Document pdfDocument = null;
    try
    {
        // Convert a HTML string with images to replace to a PDF document object
        pdfDocument = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToPdfDocumentObject(urlTextBox.Text);

        // Replace the images selected in HTML using special attributes with images from local file system
        foreach (HtmlElementMapping imageElementInfo in htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlElementsMappingOptions.HtmlElementsMappingResult)
        {
            PdfPage imagePdfPage = imageElementInfo.PdfRectangles[0].PdfPage;
            RectangleF imageRectangle = imageElementInfo.PdfRectangles[0].Rectangle;

            ImageElement newImageElement = new ImageElement(imageRectangle.X, imageRectangle.Y, imageRectangle.Width, imageRectangle.Height,
                            Server.MapPath("~/DemoAppFiles/Input/Images/box.jpg"));
            newImageElement.EnlargeEnabled = true;
            imagePdfPage.AddElement(newImageElement);
        }

        // Save the PDF document in a memory buffer
        byte[] outPdfBuffer = pdfDocument.Save();

        // Send the PDF as response to browser

        // Set response content type
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        // Instruct the browser to open the PDF file as an attachment or inline
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=Replace_with_Higher_Quality_Images.pdf; size={0}", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

        // Write the PDF document buffer to HTTP response
        Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);

        // End the HTTP response and stop the current page processing
        Response.End();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the PDF document
        if (pdfDocument != null)
            pdfDocument.Close();
    }
}
```